# Витрина на django и djinja

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django, jinja2

Привет, stackowerflow, решил написать витрину на django, но возникла проблема с тем как разделять данные (хочу колонку по 5 штук(данные не всегда кратны 5)):
columns -> column1, column2,..column5.

urls.py Примерно такой:

```
products = Product.objects.order_by('-date')
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=products, 
    template_name='shop/shop.html'))
]
```

Как передать продукты в цикл jinja по 5 штук?

Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: Надо сделать несколько блоков columns с колонками по 5 штук. просто products[:5] не подойдет

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все очень просто

urls.py:

```
def subdivide_arr(arr):
    new_arr = []
    curr_index = 0
    new_arr.append([])
    for i in arr:
        new_arr[curr_index].append(i)
        if len(new_arr[curr_index]) >= 4:
            new_arr.append([])
            curr_index += 1
    for i in range(4 - len(new_arr[-1])):
        new_arr[-1].append(None)
    return new_arr

products = subdivide_arr(Product.objects.order_by('-date'))
```

shop.html:

```
<div class="title as-text-centered">
    <h1> Welcome to the shop!</h1>
</div>
<div class="showcase">
{% for columns in object_list %}
    <div class="columns">
    {% for product in columns %}
        <div class="column has-text-centered">
        {% if product != None %}
            <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="" style="width:200px; height: 200px" class="product_preview">
            <br>
            <a href="/shop/{{ product.id }}" class="product_name">{{ product.name }}</a>
            <br>
            <a class="product_price button is-danger" href="/shop/{{ product.id }}">{{ product.price }}₴</a>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```